# Average Analytics Function On GA360 Visit ID for LatencyTracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Looking to get the average latencyTracking for a visitid out of our GA 360 export.

Setup the following query but getting the following error and I'm not sure why since all these are all aggregate functions:  *SELECT list expression references hits.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:5]*

```
select 
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) as visitStartTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime) OVER (PARTITION BY visitid) as avgServerResponseTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime) OVER (PARTITION BY visitid) as avgServerConnectionTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime) OVER (PARTITION BY visitid) as avgdomInteractiveTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime) OVER (PARTITION BY visitid) as avgpageLoadTime
from `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_2018*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
where hits.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime is not null
group by visitStartTime
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your query written - AVG() is not just [`Aggregate Function`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions) but rather [`Aggregate Analytic Function`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_analytic_functions).

To make it work you can remove OVER() so AVG() will really become aggregate function here corresponding to GROUP BY

```
select 
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) as visitStartTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime) as avgServerResponseTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime) as avgServerConnectionTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime) as avgdomInteractiveTime,
AVG(hits.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime) as avgpageLoadTime
from `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_2018*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
where hits.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime is not null
group by visitStartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `windows` and `group by` in conjunction can be confusing.
In your case it is not even necessary, neither is the flattening - you can write simple subqueries to get your numbers per session:

```sql
SELECT   
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AS visitStartTime,
  (
    SELECT AVG(latencyTracking.serverResponseTime) 
    FROM t.hits
    WHERE latencyTracking.serverResponseTime IS NOT NULL) AS avgServerResponseTime,
  (
    SELECT AVG(latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime)
    FROM t.hits
    WHERE latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime IS NOT NULL) AS avgServerConnectionTime,
  (
    SELECT AVG(latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime)
    FROM t.hits
    WHERE latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime IS NOT NULL ) AS avgdomInteractiveTime,
  (
    SELECT AVG(latencyTracking.pageLoadTime)
    FROM t.hits
    WHERE latencyTracking.pageLoadTime IS NOT NULL ) AS avgpageLoadTime
FROM `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_2018*`
```

It also doesn't involve grouping which makes it faster.